# How do I know when Extjs getFilter completes?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want when the Extjs getFilter () is complete, add a new line. Which sign to know if getFilter () is complete?

I am using extjs version 2.5

```
    _ID = selRec.data.ID;
    _seletedIndex = App.grdVoucher.store.data.length > 0 ? idx : 0;
    new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        App.stoSeries.suspendEvents();
        App.grdSeries.getFilterPlugin().clearFilters();
        App.grdSeries.getFilterPlugin().getFilter('ID').setValue([_ID, ""]);
        App.grdSeries.getFilterPlugin().getFilter('ID').setActive(true);
        App.stoSeries.resumeEvents();
        resolve()
    }).then(x=>{
        if (HQ.isInsert) {
            var record = HQ.store.findRecord(App.stoSeries, _keySeries, ['']);
            if (!record) {
                HQ.store.insertBlank(App.stoSeries, _keySeries);
            }
        }
    })
};
```